# How can I highlight a cell in a table with grouped rows and columns all with different colors

Tags: css

I have successfully created groups of rows and columns with alternating colors.  I tried to use colgroups and tbody, but gave up on colgroup, col :nth* because I could not get them to play well with alternating both rows and columns.  I am applying classes as I build the table.  HTML example follows:

```
<table class="syslibblock">
  <tr class="rowgroup0">
    <TD class="colgroup0">1-1-1</td>
    <TD class="colgroup0">1-1-2</td>
    <TD class="colgroup1">1-2-1</td>
    <TD class="colgroup1">1-2-2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowgroup1">
    <TD class="mark colgroup0">2-1-1</td>
    <TD class="mark colgroup0">2-1-2</td>
    <TD class="colgroup1">2-2-1</td>
    <TD class="colgroup1">2-2-2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am setting alternating background colors with the following CSS:

```
.syslibblock .rowgroup0 .colgroup0 {
    background: #004040;
}
.syslibblock .rowgroup0 .colgroup1 {
    background: #404000;
}
.syslibblock .rowgroup1 .colgroup0 {
    background: #006060;
}
.syslibblock .rowgroup1 .colgroup1 {
    background: #606000;
}
```

This is working as expected.  My problem is that I want to mark some cells by applying special formatting to cells 2-1-1 and 2-1-2.  I have added a second class 'mark' to those cells, but have not found a way to catch those cells from css.

I expected that one of the following selectors would do the job because they are more specific, but they don't. (There are actually a set of 4 selectors just like the ones that color the backgrounds.)

```
.syslibblock .rowgroup1 .mark .colgroup0 {}

.syslibblock .rowgroup1 .colgroup0 .mark {}
```

I am new to css, and have no idea what I am missing.  An ideal answer would be the correct selector to catch my 'mark'ed cells.  If I should start over with a totally different strategy, that is fine too.  I am using PHP to generate the table, but believe the answer should be in the CSS domain.

A verbose explanation of how/why your solution works would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To select some element that has multiple classes you don't separate the classes by a space. You do it like so:

`.syslibblock .rowgroup1 .mark.colgroup0 {}`

For an element with 3 classes, say this one:

```
<div class="a b c"></div>
```

you'd write

`.a.b.c{}`

[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/tftoo9co/)

Answer (score 0):

What you missing is that you should:

```
.syslibblock .rowgroup1 .mark{
  background: #000;
}
```

Not:

```
.syslibblock .rowgroup1 .mark .colgroup0 {}
```

Because there is a space in class as `.a .b .c`, it is a parent-child relation not a sibling relation.

[There is a link.](http://jsbin.com/dasudu/3/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.mark` as special class to be applied when you need it, without considering your HTML TR/TD structure in the selector.
This approach allow you more flexibility.

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zncdwxwu/1/

```
.syslibblock .mark {
    background: red !important;
    color: yellow;
}
```

In your case, as you are using the property background in `.mark`,  you need also use `!important`, in order override and apply your new color.

Alternatively, if you wish to consider your HTML structure TR/TD in your CSS selector, you can avoid `!important` and using the following code;

http://jsfiddle.net/zncdwxwu/2/

```
.syslibblock .rowgroup1 .mark{
    background: red;
    color: yellow;
}
```